# Execl 2010 POL Save As PDF crashing

Tags: wine, pdf, playonlinux, microsoft-office, microsoft-word

I am running Microsoft Excel 2010 through PlayOnLinux (POL v4.2.10 with Wine v2.22) on Ubuntu 16.04. The Save As PDF function works for most Excel files but sometimes crashes for certain Excel files with the error message: 
`Microsoft Excel has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience`

[image]

This always happens with the same Excel files and it happens each time I try to Save As PDF those specific files. I haven't been able to figure out the difference between the Excel files that crash and those that do not crash.

As a work-around, I print to the cups-pdf package as a printer. But this is not ideal because the text in the PDF cannot be selected when the cups-pdf is used.

Comment: Have you tried opening the document in question with LibreOffice and using the built-in "export to PDF" function there?

Comment: @Gerowen - yes that worked so it's a better work-around than cups-pdf because the text is not selectable - thanks! 
Still, it would be good avoid needing a work-around and fix the problem with Excel.